# Model for collection imported in database from json file

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

If I import JSON file in MongoDB do I still have to create a model for this collection in my app?

I have an imported collection called "places" in my MongoDB using mongoimport. Now in my app I would like to get some data from this collection, is it mandatory first to create a model for this imported collection and then query the collection or there is another approach for this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to create a model for your app as Mongo is schemaless you don't need an ORM but to be sure that you have the correct fields to query.

I don't know mongoose but in my idea you app need a connector to the database i.e declare your database inside your app

Then inside your app after loading the connection to the database
you can query directly your database. Something like:

```
var myCity = db.place.findOne({"city": input.city})
```

> I apologize for the quality of the answer but I have no clue regarding the input or the app or the driver.